# Slide Up/Down with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to slide up/down or just show and hide div but it's not working. My code:

```
<div class="facilities">
            <div id="facheader">
                <div class="facheadname">
                    Facilities
                </div>
                <div class="facheaderbutton">
                    &#9651;
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="factable">
                <table border="0">
                         <tr><div class="factableheader">
                         <th>Name</th><th>City</th><th>Country</th><th>Compliance Certification</th><th>Audit History</th><th>Date</th><th>Remediation History</th><th>Date</th></div>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                         <td>Kowloon</td><td>Hong Kong</td><td>Hong Kong</td><td>cGMP-FDA</td><td>Compliant cGMP-SeerPharma</td><td>12/12/10</td><td>Clean room staff training – IRB-C</td><td>01/03/05</td>
                         </tr>
                 </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried code - it's hiding content but not showing when pressed again:

```
$('#facheader').click(function(){
            if ($('#factable').is(':hidden')){
                $('#factable').show();}
            else{
                $('.contclickedinfo').hide();
            }
            return false;
        });



        $('#factable').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(document).click(function() {
            $('#factable').hide();
        });
```

I also tried these but they are not working at all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#facheader').click(function(){
        $('#factable').slideUp(), function(){
        $('#factable').slideDown();
    });
});
```

and

```
$('#facheader').toggle(function(){ 

        $('#factable').slideUp(800);  // Text slides up 
        }, function(){ 

        $('#factable').slideDown(800); // Text slides down
    });
```

Comment: [May be you should try this](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Comment: You final code snippet works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/QMLQC/

Comment: @Krishnik: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If that link were to break for some reason your answer would become useless. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short with toggle function

```
$("#facheader").click(function(){
    $("#factable").slideToggle(); /* between () you can define speed in MS */
});
```

Because it's not a link that triggers the slide, you don't need to return false or stopPropagation.

Something which is strange is:

```
<tr><div class="factableheader">
```

When browsers see this, they will put your  outside your table.

Are you using multiple DIV's with the same ID?

Comment: I tried all your solutions but it's not working. You can see it here when I press on Facilities nothing happens: http://lordmonarch.net84.net/serviceProviders.html

Comment: Thats because your .facilities has a `z-index: -1` which makes it not clickable. Remove the `z-index: - 1` and it will work.

Comment: Please put it on solved, so others don't have to start looking when the result is already here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#facheader').click(function() { 
    if ($('#factable').is(':visible'))
        $('#factable').slideUp(800);  // Text slides up 
    else
        $('#factable').slideDown(800); // Text slides down
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#facheader').click(function() {
    if ($('#factable').is(':visible')){
        $('#factable').hide();
    } else {
        $('#factable').show();
    }

    return false;
});
```

That should work just the way you want to. I changed the element you wanted to hide, because you picked a different element. Besides, the `:visible` selector has served me better than `:hidden`. I'm not sure why `:hidden` doesn't always work the way we expect it to work.